# Can't compile a Grails project

Tags: grails, ggts

I'm super new to Grails, so I apologize for asking something too easy:

I tried to do a **Project** > **Clean** and I get:

```
Welcome to Grails 1.3.7 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: /Users/shamoon/.sdkman/candidates/grails/1.3.7/
Base Directory: /Users/shamoon/GoogleDrive/Sites/MySite/MySite/MySiteServer
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 1363ms.
Running script /Users/shamoon/.sdkman/candidates/grails/1.3.7/scripts/RunApp.groovy
Environment set to development
     [copy] Copied 4 empty directories to 2 empty directories under /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/MySiteServer/resources
     [copy] Copied 13 empty directories to 9 empty directories under /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/MySiteServer/resources
     [copy] Copied 2 empty directories to 1 empty directory under /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/MySiteServer/resources
     [copy] Copied 5 empty directories to 2 empty directories under /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/MySiteServer/resources
     [copy] Copied 3 empty directories to 1 empty directory under /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/MySiteServer/resources
     [copy] Copied 3 empty directories to 2 empty directories under /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/MySiteServer/resources
     [copy] Copied 2 empty directories to 1 empty directory under /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/MySiteServer/resources
     [copy] Copied 6 empty directories to 5 empty directories under /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/MySiteServer/resources
     [copy] Copied 1 empty directory to 1 empty directory under /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/MySiteServer/resources
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/MySiteServer/resources
     [copy] Copied 6 empty directories to 2 empty directories under /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/MySiteServer/resources
     [copy] Copied 1 empty directory to 1 empty directory under /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/MySiteServer/resources
     [copy] Copied 4 empty directories to 4 empty directories under /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/MySiteServer/resources
     [copy] Copied 2 empty directories to 1 empty directory under /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/MySiteServer/resources
     [copy] Copied 2 empty directories to 2 empty directories under /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/MySiteServer/resources
     [copy] Copied 1 empty directory to 1 empty directory under /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/MySiteServer/resources
     [copy] Copied 3 empty directories to 2 empty directories under /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/MySiteServer/resources
     [copy] Copied 1 empty directory to 1 empty directory under /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/MySiteServer/resources
  [groovyc] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/MySiteServer/plugin-classes
  [groovyc] Compiling 258 source files to /Users/shamoon/GoogleDrive/Sites/MySite/MySite/MySiteServer/target/classes
  [groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
  [groovyc] Compile error during compilation with javac.
  [groovyc] /var/folders/t2/czsgnnwx4ys_86hfq04m822r0000gn/T/groovy-generated-3051460305321062736-java-source/iq4/model/Item.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
  [groovyc] protected  ItemType getItemType() { return (ItemType)null;}
  [groovyc]            ^
  [groovyc]   symbol:   class ItemType
  [groovyc]   location: class Item
  [groovyc] /Users/shamoon/GoogleDrive/Sites/MySite/MySite/MySiteServer/src/java/iq4/model/QueryResult.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
  [groovyc]     ItemType itemType;
  [groovyc]     ^
  [groovyc]   symbol:   class ItemType
  [groovyc]   location: class QueryResult<T>
  [groovyc]   where T is a type-variable:
  [groovyc]     T extends Object declared in class QueryResult
  [groovyc] /Users/shamoon/GoogleDrive/Sites/MySite/MySite/MySiteServer/src/java/iq4/model/QueryResult.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
  [groovyc]     ItemType rowType;
  [groovyc]     ^
  [groovyc]   symbol:   class ItemType
  [groovyc]   location: class QueryResult<T>
  [groovyc]   where T is a type-variable:
  [groovyc]     T extends Object declared in class QueryResult
  [groovyc] /Users/shamoon/GoogleDrive/Sites/MySite/MySite/MySiteServer/src/java/iq4/model/QueryResult.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
  [groovyc]     public ItemType getItemType() {
  [groovyc]            ^
  [groovyc]   symbol:   class ItemType
  [groovyc]   location: class QueryResult<T>
  [groovyc]   where T is a type-variable:
  [groovyc]     T extends Object declared in class QueryResult
  [groovyc] /Users/shamoon/GoogleDrive/Sites/MySite/MySite/MySiteServer/src/java/iq4/model/QueryResult.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
  [groovyc]     public void setItemType(ItemType itemType) {
  [groovyc]                             ^
  [groovyc]   symbol:   class ItemType
  [groovyc]   location: class QueryResult<T>
  [groovyc]   where T is a type-variable:
  [groovyc]     T extends Object declared in class QueryResult
  [groovyc] /Users/shamoon/GoogleDrive/Sites/MySite/MySite/MySiteServer/src/java/iq4/model/QueryResult.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
  [groovyc]     public ItemType getRowType() {
  [groovyc]            ^
  [groovyc]   symbol:   class ItemType
  [groovyc]   location: class QueryResult<T>
  [groovyc]   where T is a type-variable:
  [groovyc]     T extends Object declared in class QueryResult
  [groovyc] /Users/shamoon/GoogleDrive/Sites/MySite/MySite/MySiteServer/src/java/iq4/model/QueryResult.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
  [groovyc]     public void setRowType(ItemType rowType) {
  [groovyc]                            ^
  [groovyc]   symbol:   class ItemType
  [groovyc]   location: class QueryResult<T>
  [groovyc]   where T is a type-variable:
  [groovyc]     T extends Object declared in class QueryResult
  [groovyc] /Users/shamoon/GoogleDrive/Sites/MySite/MySite/MySiteServer/src/java/iq4/servlet/AWSBridgeServlet.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
  [groovyc] import iq4.model.ItemType;
  [groovyc]                 ^
  [groovyc]   symbol:   class ItemType
  [groovyc]   location: package iq4.model
  [groovyc] /var/folders/t2/czsgnnwx4ys_86hfq04m822r0000gn/T/groovy-generated-3051460305321062736-java-source/iq4/model/Task.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
  [groovyc] public  PriorityType getPriority() { return (PriorityType)null;}
  [groovyc]         ^
  [groovyc]   symbol:   class PriorityType
  [groovyc]   location: class Task
  [groovyc] /var/folders/t2/czsgnnwx4ys_86hfq04m822r0000gn/T/groovy-generated-3051460305321062736-java-source/iq4/model/Task.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
  [groovyc] public  void setPriority(PriorityType value) { }
  [groovyc]                          ^
  [groovyc]   symbol:   class PriorityType
  [groovyc]   location: class Task
  [groovyc] /var/folders/t2/czsgnnwx4ys_86hfq04m822r0000gn/T/groovy-generated-3051460305321062736-java-source/iq4/model/Task.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
  [groovyc] public  TaskStatusType getStatus() { return (TaskStatusType)null;}
  [groovyc]         ^
  [groovyc]   symbol:   class TaskStatusType
  [groovyc]   location: class Task
  [groovyc] /var/folders/t2/czsgnnwx4ys_86hfq04m822r0000gn/T/groovy-generated-3051460305321062736-java-source/iq4/model/Task.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
  [groovyc] public  void setStatus(TaskStatusType value) { }
  [groovyc]                        ^
  [groovyc]   symbol:   class TaskStatusType
  [groovyc]   location: class Task
  [groovyc] /var/folders/t2/czsgnnwx4ys_86hfq04m822r0000gn/T/groovy-generated-3051460305321062736-java-source/iq4/model/Task.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
  [groovyc] protected  ItemType getItemType() { return (ItemType)null;}
  [groovyc]            ^
  [groovyc]   symbol:   class ItemType
  [groovyc]   location: class Task
  [groovyc] /var/folders/t2/czsgnnwx4ys_86hfq04m822r0000gn/T/groovy-generated-3051460305321062736-java-source/iq4/model/Job.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
  [groovyc] public  WorkHours getWorkHours() { return (WorkHours)null;}
  [groovyc]         ^
  [groovyc]   symbol:   class WorkHours
  [groovyc]   location: class Job
  [groovyc] /var/folders/t2/czsgnnwx4ys_86hfq04m822r0000gn/T/groovy-generated-3051460305321062736-java-source/iq4/model/Job.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
  [groovyc] public  void setWorkHours(WorkHours value) { }
  [groovyc]                           ^
  [groovyc]   symbol:   class WorkHours
  [groovyc]   location: class Job
  [groovyc] /var/folders/t2/czsgnnwx4ys_86hfq04m822r0000gn/T/groovy-generated-3051460305321062736-java-source/iq4/model/Job.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
  [groovyc] public  Internship getInternship() { return (Internship)null;}
  [groovyc]         ^
  [groovyc]   symbol:   class Internship
  [groovyc]   location: class Job
  [groovyc] /var/folders/t2/czsgnnwx4ys_86hfq04m822r0000gn/T/groovy-generated-3051460305321062736-java-source/iq4/model/Job.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
  [groovyc] public  void setInternship(Internship value) { }

  ....

  [groovyc] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
  [groovyc] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
  [groovyc] 32 errors
  [groovyc] 1 error
Compilation error: Compilation Failed
```

My colleague can get this up and running on her machine. We're both using the same version of Java, Grails, and GGTS. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler can't find the 'java' files which are returned in those functions.  Check if it is in the proper folder with 'public' access specifier.  If it is in a google drive check if it is accessible.  If your colleague has this app up and running on her system, it might be probably because of the inaccessibility of java source files.  Check and give more info on it

Answer (score 1):

Grails 1.3.7 is a very old version. I recommend you to use a actual supported version

Comment: Agree absolutely that 1.3.7 should not be used to create new projects, but I would add that Grails 3.x is not ready for prime time IMO (for example, missing Grails 3 versions of third-party plugins are not ready).